# Why isn't my pom being executed correctly when using Android Studio/IntelliJ?

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, android-manifest, android-studio

I have an Android application which is built with Maven.
Using the buildnumber-maven-plugin and maven-resources-plugin I insert the maven project version and the git commit hash into the AndroidManifest.
The `create` goal of buildnumber-maven-plugin runs in the `validate` phase and the `resources` goal of the maven-resources-plugin runs in the `initialize` phase.

When built through the command-line (with `mvn install`) all works fine and the build number appears correctly in the produced manifest.

However when building through Android Studio or IntelliJ the git commit hash is not present (the Maven property is not replaced with the actual value) in the manifest but the maven project version is.

**Why?**

FYI: Android Studio runs the Maven phase process-resources before a Make, so it should work.

On the command-line I am using Maven 3.0.3, so it could be a version issue (though I can't find out what version IntelliJ uses).

Here is my POM's build element:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/filtered-manifest</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>AndroidManifest.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.buildnumber.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                <shortRevisionLength>6</shortRevisionLength>
                <revisionOnScmFailure>000000</revisionOnScmFailure>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.resources.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <androidManifestFile>${project.build.directory}/filtered-manifest/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And the versionName in my AndroidManifest file is:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.somecompany"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="${project.version}-${buildNumber}" >
```

From commandline both ${project.version} and ${buildNumber} are filled in correctly with their values, from IntelliJ ${buildNumber} is not and just appears as "${buildNumber}": this would indicate (since I have set `revisionOnScmFailure`) that the plugin fails to run at all.

I have tried changing the `create` goal to run in the `initialize` phase (in case IntelliJ was skipping out `validate`) but that made no difference.

Comment: Had any progress with this issue?

Comment: Sadly I have not yet; as workaround you can use the maven "install" task from IntelliJ rather than "make"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IntelliJ has it's own internal build system much like any other IDE and is able to build projects without the help of external tools. Intellij also integrates with Maven by interpreting the pom.xml from your project and intructing it to build based on the configuration you have defined. This works pretty well with most compilation tasks but starts to fall over when you bring in more complex plugins such as the buildnumber-maven-plugin. Unfortunately IntelliJ has no internal equivilent to handle this plugin so the ${buildNumber} property is never populated.

The possible workarounds are:

1. Don't build your project with IntelliJ's built in system, use the "Maven Projects" panel which you can show by going to "View" > "Tool Windows" > "Maven Projects". This gives you access to all of the standard Maven phases and other features.
2. In your IntelliJ "run configuration" add an environment variable called "buildNumber" and give it any value you like, for example: buildNumber=DEV. This will make the the buildNumber property available during the build process and populate the property, it won't however update from your SCM.

We use the first workaround on a multi-module maven project as we too have hit similar limitations with the buildnumber-maven-plugin. We also use solution 2 when we need to run an integration test in IntelliJ as the buildNumber property is required by our code to display version information, as long as we give it any value it's happy.

I hope this is somewhat useful to you, the only real solution would be for IntelliJ's internal build system to have some understanding of the buildnumber-maven-plugin and expose the correct properties to the environment during the build process.

Comment: But it doesn't **just** import the POM, it also *supposed* to run the Maven phase process-resources, which should result in the buildnumber plugin being run. Thanks for the answers. As far as I'm concerned in our case 1. is not acceptable because few devs will put up with the build time increase, but 2. will probably do.
I will hold out marking this as correct to allow some time for any other answers.

Comment: I have found it difficult to find out what IntelliJ's compiler is actually doing when it interprets the pom.xml in the past, there doesn't seem to be a whole lot of information out there. My understanding is that IntelliJ doesn't involve maven during the "process-resources" phase (or any phase for that matter) but has it's own implementation of "process resources" which is configured by reading the pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What I've done is:

- Go to the Maven tool window
- Go to a project that uses buildnumber-maven-plugin
- Expand `Plugins`
- Find and expand buildnumber plugin
- Below that you find buildnumber:create item - right click on that and select `Execute After Build`

Works like a charm for me.